# Is it possible to persist range objects ? Current version of office-js does not support bookmarks

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I want to bookmark some text in the word document and add some text after this bookmark at some later time. As current version of Word Api does not support bookmarks I was wondering if this can be achieved by persisting range objects in word settings or a database.

Comment: Look at using Content Controls to mark "targets" in a document. They can be formatted to not be visible, if that's a concern.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister. How do I uniquely identify a content control ? Like how do I load up the content control the next time I open this particular word document.

Comment: It has name and tag properties. Look in the API documentation.

Comment: @CindyMeister Works like a charm. Thank you